# react convert array to object of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my react project I got the following structure (object of objects with keys):

```
const listItems = {
  1:{
    id: 1,
    depth: 0,
    children: [2,5]
  },
  2:{
    id: 2,
    depth: 1,
    children: [3,4],
    parentIndex: 1, 
    disabled: false 
  },
  3:{
    id: 3,
    depth: 2,
    parentIndex: 2,
    disabled: false
  },
}
```

after doing this:

```
let listItemsModified = Object.keys(listItems).map((i, listItem, inputArray) => {

 listItems[i]._styles = {
    root: {overflow: 'hidden'}
 };
  return listItems[i];
});
```

I get just array of objects:

```
[ 
  {
    id: 1,
    depth: 0,
    children: [2,5],
    _styles: 'some styles here'
  },{
    id: 2,
    depth: 1,
    children: [3,4],
    parentIndex: 1, 
    _styles: 'some styles here',
    disabled: false 
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    depth: 2,
    parentIndex: 2,
    _styles: 'some styles here',
    disabled: false
  }
]
```

but I need an object of objects as I had initially, like this:

```
{
  1:{
    id: 1,
    depth: 0,
    _styles: 'some styles here',
    children: [2,5]
  },
  2:{
    id: 2,
    depth: 1,
    children: [3,4],
    parentIndex: 1, 
    _styles: 'some styles here',
    disabled: false 
  },
  3:{
    id: 3,
    depth: 2,
    parentIndex: 2,
    _styles: 'some styles here',
    disabled: false
  },
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
Object.keys(listitemsModified).reduce((array, key) => {
    return {key: listitemsModified[key]}
}, {})
```

but I get only 1 object instead of object of objects. Any ideas how to fix this would be welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work on the original `listItems`:

```js
    const listItems = {
      1:{
        id: 1,
        depth: 0,
        children: [2,5]
      },
      2:{
        id: 2,
        depth: 1,
        children: [3,4],
        parentIndex: 1, 
        disabled: false 
      },
      3:{
        id: 3,
        depth: 2,
        parentIndex: 2,
        disabled: false
      },
    }

    const result = Object.keys(listItems).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = {
            ...listItems[key],
            _styles: {
                root: {overflow: 'hidden'}
            }
        };
        return acc;
    }, {});
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
Object.keys(listitemsModified).reduce((array, key) => {
    return {
      ...array,
      [key]: listitemsModified[key],
    }
}, {})
```

I left variable names as is, but `array` is actually not an array, but the state of your `reduce`-function (which initially is `{}`, and on each iteration will be expanded). I think a better name would be `accumulator`/`acc`

Comment: You can write this in one line: `Object.keys(listitemsModified).reduce((array, item) => ({...array, [item.id]: item}), {})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to apply the styles and return the original structure, rather than converting the structure twice:

```js
const listItems = {
  1: { id: 1, depth: 0, children: [2,5] },
  2: { id: 2, depth: 1, children: [3,4], parentIndex: 1, disabled: false },
  3: { id: 3, depth: 2, parentIndex: 2, disabled: false }
}

const styles = { root: { overflow: 'hidden' } }

console.log(Object.entries(listItems).reduce((a, [k,v]) => ({...a, [k]: {...v, _styles: styles}}), {}))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
listitemsModified.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
    acc[i+1] = cur;
    return acc },{})
```